# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am attempting to build my first Xamarin android application.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community

I am new to Xamarin so apologies for any errors.

I created a simple project and then added a new project of type "Class Library (Android)"

I added simple async function and everything worked perfectly.

I then added my API which has a swagger definition using the Add > REST API Client

It downloaded my API and built the client for me - all looking great!

I'm getting really excited at this point.

But, the project will no longer build reporting an error of:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll'
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App5

I have hunted high and low on the internet looking for a solution but just cannot seem to fix the problem.

My initial "Hello World" function was working perfectly using async/await.

I don't understand what adding this new API Client has done and is using differently.

Can anyone shed any light on how to solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to add the REST Api to a PCL project, not an Android App project or Android Library project. See:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/03/24/introducing-the-azure-api-apps-tools-for-visual-studio-2013/

> The generated client code is also supported in Portable Class Library projects, so you can use them from any platform supporting PCL, like Windows Phone 8.1 and Universal apps, as well as apps written targeting Android and iOS with Xamarin.